# What are the essential properties of a PWM signal that can be captured with an oscilloscope?

Tags: pwm, oscilloscope

My question is regarding general guidelines when it comes to using oscilloscope captures in a professional-grade report to be presented to people working with signal processing, embedded systems, etc. Although there are a few obvious ones (i.e. cursors and labels), I was hoping to hear from the community about what kind of information do you think would be the most useful on an oscilloscope screen capture?

The focus is on different characteristics of a PWM signal.

To narrow down the question - I am looking to put together a small presentation (~ 15-20 slides including pictorial slides and bullet point info) that gives an overview of a PWM module on a specific uC. One of my main assets for facilitating this task is an oscilloscope. The purpose of this question was to ask fellow users for an advice regarding possible properties of a PWM signal that may be of interest to a professional embedded systems engineer evaluating a new board.

Comment: This is not really possible to say, as it's entirely dependent on what information you're trying to show, and the purpose of the report.

Comment: Ambiguous as freq is useful for AC stuff but not so for DC... Personally I use scopeshots as an overview and export to CSV to then extract useful info. Sometimes cursors if risetime or period is the focal point

Comment: At this point I am looking to show as many characteristics of an uC-generated PWM signal as possible

Comment: In my experience in the actual professional world, nobody ever writes a report when they can get away with just a powerpoint, and the standard for quality of illustrations is "whatever I can get done as quickly as possible". Unless the presentation is to be shown to a top boss, then suddenly 3 levels of manager above you will want to tell you to make the background a different color.

Comment: You really have to know what you are doing the measurement for. You then need to capture the right waveforms to demonstrate the required into. Don't forget to show where on the schematic the waveforms were taken, and what the units are if this is not labeled on the trace. The best engineering is not done by following set rules but by thinking through what is required and delivering that in the best way.

Comment: A slightly different perspective: I worked in a field that used oscilloscopes as the primary data acquisition device for publishable research. In that case we would extract the data from the oscilloscope via GPIB (today: ethernet or usb), and then fit and plot the graphs in matlab/python in *analytical units* (e.g. converted from Volts or digiitzing units to temperature, pressure, etc.). The standards for the fit and graph were the applicable journal's standards for the figures and data being presented.

Comment: In response to your edits, it still depends highly on EXACTLY what you're trying to show.  Personally, I think simple timing diagrams would be more useful than scope captures.  Indeed, this is how such info would be presented in data sheets and app notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal PWM signal will have the following characteriestics, high time, low time, high voltage, low voltage. Your scope trace graticule needs to be annotated with at least seconds/div and volts/div. If you have time and voltage markers to give these in numbers, then so much the better. These can be illustrated using a cycle or two per screen.

A non-ideal PWM signal will further have limited or unequal slew rate on rising and falling edges, overshoot after rising and falling edges and ripple and droop on high and low regions. These may need the voltage and time scales increasing to highlight just these parts of the waveform.

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking about this entirely backwards.  Think about what DATA you need to show to make the report, and THEN think about what you need to do to make the scope show that.  If the scope can't show it adequately, then export the data, bring it in to your own presentation package, and make your own graphics for the report.

Comment: Also consider the audience. The report should be very different if made for a reporter, versus a PCB fab team.

Comment: or, indeed, if the report is part of a milestone review or some aspect of a record for regulatory purposes there may be a call for extra rigor.

Comment: @ScottSeidman It's definitely a mistake on my part for making this too broad, and I am open to all suggestions of how to improve (or narrow down, if these two are synonymous in this case) my question - the intention was to ask what kind of properties of a PWM signal may be of primary interest and what kind of functions may an average digital oscilloscope offer to check these properties?

Answer (score 1):

A 'professional' screen capture will show enough signal information so you could reconstruct the signal if necessary. That includes time and amplitude. Since older scopes have lower resolution, you may need to put less signals in one capture. Newer scopes have many of measurements and you can clutter the capture with unnecessary information. Capturing more than three or four periods of the signal is redundant. If there is an error in the signal you will want to turn on the appropriate filtering to capture that. If there is frequency content, include the FFT on a separate capture.